# Converting Video from Camera to Byte Array Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

I am familiar with producing a byte array from `UIImage`. But how do I do it from a video? This is what I have in the `imagePickerController` delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

```
if let media = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let byteArray = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(media, 1.0)
        print("hi")
    } else {
        //stuck here
    }
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("dataUploaded").setValue("uploaded")
    uploaded = true
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Videos work slightly differently to images in UIImagePickerController. Instead of providing the raw video data, `UIImagePickerController` returns a URL of the video file.

Use the `info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` to get the URL of the video file. You can load the bytes of the file using `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` initialiser.

E.g.

```
if let fileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL { 
     let bytes = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL) 
}
```

Note: `bytes` is an optional, since loading the video can fail.

Usually the video will be an MOV or MP4 video file, with content encoded with the .H264 codec, although other formats do exist.